# Is it possible to bypass a layer of security to access a given page of a website?

Tags: html, reactjs

A lot of web3 websites are emerging were we need to have, for example, a nft of a given collection to access some subpages of a web app.

But I don't understand something. Since we have the code of the web app, could someone just download the html source, remove the nft check, in that case, and access the subpage?

I know that it isn't that simple to modify an app, especially if they use something like React, but would that be feasible?

I guess not, otherwise they won't do it like this, but I don't get why it isn't possible.

Comment: Yeah, it's really easy to download, and republish all frontend parts of any app. But backend logic is much harder. Isn't most web3 stuff open source anyway, so all the code is already public...

Comment: But this question really doesn't fit within StackOverflow's guidelines, see **[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Generally, you need to have a clear, well defined issue, explain what's not working as it should, and share the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, yes they could. Any code that is written on the client-side can be tampered with. If the code on the client-side contains the information necessary to display a particular element, then from a security standpoint, you could assume that someone who's interested enough could reverse-engineer the code and force that element to display, even if you have JavaScript checks that are intended to block it.

The best way for such an application to *actually* stop important data from being displayed to the user is to only send the data once the *server* validates that the given user has permission to access something. If the data never gets sent to the client to begin with, and the server is secure there isn't really anything they can do about it.

Another way is to make it more *difficult* for clients to reverse-engineer the code, by minifying the code and having a *whole lot* of it. Minified code is very hard to read. For example, it could take quite some effort to read through 6000 lines of minified code and figure out enough about what's going on to make the changes you want. (Someone may get lucky and happen to stumble onto something close to the listeners they can see attached to elements on the page that gives them what they want - but they may not.)

In general: don't trust anything done on the client-side. The only way to be absolutely certain that data isn't displayed to those who shouldn't be able to see it is to never send it to the client in the first place.